# I seem to be blocked, despite custom bridges. How can I get around this error?

Tags: directory, encryption

```
3/29/2017 11:51:07 AM.600 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
3/29/2017 11:51:07 AM.600 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
3/29/2017 11:51:07 AM.600 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
3/29/2017 11:51:07 AM.600 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
3/29/2017 11:51:08 AM.500 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server 
3/29/2017 11:51:08 AM.800 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server 
3/29/2017 11:54:05 AM.600 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
3/29/2017 11:54:05 AM.600 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
3/29/2017 11:54:05 AM.600 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
3/29/2017 11:54:06 AM.400 [NOTICE] Delaying directory fetches: DisableNetwork is set. 
3/29/2017 11:54:23 AM.600 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
3/29/2017 11:54:23 AM.600 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
3/29/2017 11:54:23 AM.600 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
3/29/2017 11:54:23 AM.600 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
3/29/2017 11:54:48 AM.900 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
3/29/2017 11:54:48 AM.900 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
3/29/2017 11:54:48 AM.900 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
3/29/2017 11:54:48 AM.900 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server. (DONE; DONE; count 8; recommendation warn; host A2C13B7DFCAB1CBF3A884B6EB99A98067AB6EF44 at 0.0.2.0:3) 
3/29/2017 11:54:48 AM.900 [WARN] 8 connections have failed: 
3/29/2017 11:54:48 AM.900 [WARN]  8 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
3/29/2017 11:55:08 AM.000 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
3/29/2017 11:55:08 AM.000 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
3/29/2017 11:55:08 AM.000 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
3/29/2017 11:55:08 AM.000 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
3/29/2017 11:55:24 AM.300 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
3/29/2017 11:55:24 AM.300 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
3/29/2017 11:55:24 AM.300 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
3/29/2017 11:59:14 AM.800 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
3/29/2017 11:59:14 AM.800 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
3/29/2017 11:59:14 AM.800 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
3/29/2017 11:59:14 AM.800 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
3/29/2017 12:00:10 PM.300 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server. (DONE; DONE; count 10; recommendation warn; host 0131CAF1A36BB8661686C931D79ED7D54BA91D4C at 45.32.234.160:443) 
3/29/2017 12:00:10 PM.300 [WARN] 22 connections have failed: 
3/29/2017 12:00:10 PM.300 [WARN]  12 connections died in state handshaking (proxy) with SSL state (No SSL object) 
3/29/2017 12:00:10 PM.300 [WARN]  9 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
3/29/2017 12:00:10 PM.300 [WARN]  1 connections died in state connect()ing with SSL state (No SSL object)
```

Comment: Did you already try fetching [other bridges](https://bridges.torproject.org/), using meek-azure or meek-amazon?

Comment: It looks like they've already tried meek: `host A2C13B7DFCAB1CBF3A884B6EB99A98067AB6EF44 at 0.0.2.0:3` is `meek-azure`. I'd be interested to know what the user sees if they visit [the "front" domain](https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com) in a normal browser, though, also if `meek-amazon` is similarly censored.